# Задаю вопрос по правописанию

Tags: правописание

возможно ли задать такое - временноисполнющий ( временно исполняющий)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно только раздельное написание (наречие + причастие, так как далее обязательно следует пояснительное слово: временно исполняющий обязанности. Поэтому, несмотря на устойчивость сочетания,  термин со слитным написанием здесь не получится, так как он должен быть самостоятельным словом Для сравнения: временнообязанные крестьяне, это исторический термин конкретного содержания.